# ValueError when installing Odoo 11 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, pip, odoo-11

I'm following [this](https://odooerpcloud.com/instalar-odoo-11-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts) guide.

When I use this.

> sudo pip3 install -r /opt/odoo11/odoo/requirements.txt

I get this error:

> Exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 262, in run
>       for req in parse_requirements(filename, finder=finder, options=options, session=session):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1632, in parse_requirements
>       req = InstallRequirement.from_line(line, comes_from, prereleases=getattr(options, "pre", None))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 173, in from_line
>       return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 71, in **init**
>       req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
>       reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
>       line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2583, in scan_list
>       "Expected ',' or end-of-list in",line,"at",line[p:]
>
> ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", "gevent==1.1.2 ; sys_platform != 'win32' and python_version < '3.7'", 'at', " ; sys_platform != 'win32' and python_version < '3.7'")
>
> Storing debug log for failure in /home/juanfro/.pip/pip.log

This is the content of requirements.txt:

> Babel==2.3.4
>
> decorator==4.0.10
>
> docutils==0.12
>
> ebaysdk==2.1.5
>
> feedparser==5.2.1
>
> gevent==1.1.2 ; sys_platform != 'win32' and python_version < '3.7'
>
> gevent==1.3.4 ; sys_platform != 'win32' and python_version >= '3.7'
>
> greenlet==0.4.10 ; python_version < '3.7'
>
> greenlet==0.4.13 ; python_version >= '3.7'
>
> html2text==2016.9.19
>
> Jinja2==2.8.1
>
> lxml==3.7.1 ; sys_platform != 'win32' and python_version < '3.7'
>
> lxml==4.2.3 ; sys_platform != 'win32' and python_version >= '3.7'
>
> lxml ; sys_platform == 'win32'
>
> Mako==1.0.4
>
> MarkupSafe==0.23
>
> mock==2.0.0
>
> num2words==0.5.4
>
> ofxparse==0.16
>
> passlib==1.6.5
>
> Pillow==4.0.0
>
> psutil==4.3.1; sys_platform != 'win32'
>
> psycopg2==2.7.3.1; sys_platform != 'win32'
>
> pydot==1.2.3
>
> pyldap==2.4.28; sys_platform != 'win32'
>
> pyparsing==2.1.10
>
> PyPDF2==1.26.0
>
> pyserial==3.1.1
>
> python-dateutil==2.5.3
>
> pytz==2016.7
>
> pyusb==1.0.0
>
> PyYAML==3.12 ; python_version < '3.7'
>
> PyYAML==3.13 ; python_version >= '3.7'
>
> qrcode==5.3
>
> reportlab==3.3.0
>
> requests==2.11.1
>
> suds-jurko==0.6
>
> vatnumber==1.2
>
> vobject==0.9.3
>
> Werkzeug==0.11.15
>
> XlsxWriter==0.9.3
>
> xlwt==1.3.*
>
> xlrd==1.0.0
>
> pypiwin32 ; sys_platform == 'win32'

My guess is that having multiple `gevent` versions is messing things up or that some kind of separator is needed at the end but I don't really know what the error is or how to go around fixing it.

I found similar problems and the answers is to use :`python -m pip install -U setuptools`
but that is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is several ways to install odoo 11

1. package installer.

according to odoo documentation, you just need to type this:

```
wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://nightly.odoo.com/11.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/odoo.list
apt-get update && apt-get install odoo
```

2. source, installer.

this is hard for beginner. but you can use this script created by Yenthe666

https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript/tree/11.0